# When are foreign exchange market hours?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, foreign-currency

This is probably a daft question. I am been googling for answers but still can't be sure about the answers I got from google.

I am trying to send money from Malaysia to the UK through Revolut. But I am a bit confused with the fee [during foreign exchange market hours](https://www.revolut.com/legal/fees#exchange).

When are foreign exchange market hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there in the link you provided. “Foreign-exchange-market hours are all hours except midnight on Friday to midnight on Sunday in London.” Just make sure not to send your money at the weekend, and remember that Malaysia is hours ahead of the UK.